# How to call a rails method create from in jQuery after success(function(json)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have form with data:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <%= form_tag class: "form-horizontal" id: "payment-form" %>
        <%= hidden_field "card_registration_url", card_preregistration['CardRegistrationURL'] %>
        <%= hidden_field "preregistration_data", card_preregistration['PreregistrationData'] %>
        <%= hidden_field "access_key", card_preregistration['AccessKey'] %>
        <%= hidden_field "id_card", card_preregistration['Id'] %>

        <fieldset>
          <div id="legend">
            <legend class="">Deposit for contract <%= @contract.title %></legend>
          </div>

          <div id="legend">
            <legend class="">Amount <%= @contract.amount %></legend>
          </div>

          <!-- Name -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <%= label "card_holder", "Card Holder's Name", class:"control-label" %>
            <div class="controls">
              <%= text_field_tag "card_holder", { id: "username", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Card Number -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <%= label "card_number", "Card number", class:"control-label" %>
            <div class="controls">
              <%= text_field_tag "card_number", { id: "card_number", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Expiry-->
          <div class="control-group">
            <%= label "expity_date", "Card Expiry Date", class:"control-label" %>
            <div class="controls">
              <%= text_field_tag "card_expiration_date", { id: "card_expiration_date", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- CVV -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <%= label "cvv", "Card CVV", class:"control-label" %>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="password" id="card_cvx" name="password_confirm" placeholder="" class="span2">
              <%= text_field_tag "card_expiration_date", { id: "card_expiration_date", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Save card -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
               <label class="checkbox" for="save_card">
                 <%= label "save_card", class:"check_box" %>
                <input type="checkbox" id="save_card" value="option1">
                Save card on file?
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Submit -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <%= button_tag "Pay now", remote: true, class: "btn btn-success" id="process" %>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
      <% end %>
    </div>

</div>
```

I send data from form to server payment system(in my example it's hidden_field "card_registration_url") by post method

**register_card.js**

```
$('#process').click(function(){
  var valuesToSubmit = $('#payment-form').serialize();
  console.log(valueToSubmit);
  $.ajax({
    url: $('#mail-form').attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
    data: valuesToSubmit['card_registration_url'],
    dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
  }).success(function(json){
    //act on result.
  });
  return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
```

If response from server all fine, need call action payments_controller/create for complete payment.

How me call action payments_controller/create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the create action you needed a `post` method, and of you have followed the **rails naming convention**, this should do it for you,

`/payments` **post** request takes you to `create` action in payments controller.

so, the ajax call you can make as,

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/payments"
});

$('#process').click(function(){
  var valuesToSubmit = $('#payment-form').serialize();
  console.log(valueToSubmit);
  $.ajax({
    url: $('#mail-form').attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
    data: valuesToSubmit['card_registration_url'],
    dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
  }).success(function(json){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/payments"
    });
  });
  return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
```

If you want to send **data** through params you can also send **data** attribute from it,

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: valuesToSubmit['card_registration_url'],  // you can send your own data
      url: "/payments"
});
```